# Standard deviation of set of predictions

Tags: regression, least-squares, prediction

What is the standard deviation of a set of predictions of an OLS regression?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but can't. Consider your set of predictions as a random vector, $X$, for which the variance is:
$$Var(X) = E((X - E(X))(X - E(X))^{T})$$

See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99560/generalization-of-variance-to-random-vectors

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Y as the dependent variable

[image]

Where SSR = Sum of the squared residuals